# converting graph to legacy xml models

Tags: xml, xslt, graph-databases, semantic-web, backwards-compatibility

My team is trying to convert a graph model (n-tuples) into a discontinuous set of legacy XML models for our org's customers that still ingest them. We're not concerned about losing data that falls outside of the subset represented by these legacy models. We are concerned with faithfully re-constructing the (sometimes complicated!) structure of these models.

We see a lot of literature about bootstrapping RDF+ from XML, but none for the inverse.

We're thinking of a [GRDDL](https://www.w3.org/TR/grddl/) approach where we'd extend the recommendation to account for unusual structures under root; we're also thinking of expressing an XML model as a series of classes that point to concepts in our graphs, and that can be manipulated with set operators and using the classes that result from those manipulations as references to XPaths in existing XSDs. Both approaches seem expensive in terms of time.

Has anyone encountered (or even thought about) this problem before? How did (or would) you address it?

Comment: Just serialize you RDF into RDF/XML... More seriously: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/topbraid-users/QVyGDD6nvUg , or some other TopBraid-related technology.